# Xcode Storyboard -> Replace child view controller via push?

Tags: ios, xcode, containers, segue

I have a view controller with a container view controller embedded in it. In this container view there is a table and if you click a certain row in that table, a new child view controller with details about this table row should be displayed. So I've just segued with a push from this to the next child view controller but this doesn't work. Or it does, but it displays the child in the whole screen and not only in the container as it should. How can I do this in Xcode?
Or what could I change in code? I'm kind of lost on this problem…I'm just using a container since basically the "header" and "footer" surounding my container are the same for the next 2 or 3 screens.

This is my current setup:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question, I think you've got the right behavior, you can't accomplish what you want by pushing a new `UIViewController`, you need to manually switch the view, Something like:

```
[currentView removeFromSuperview];
currentView = myNewViewVC.view;
[self.containerView addSubview:currentView];
```

Hope this help.